# Get instance of model depending on the type

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, factory-method

I have two kinds of notes: ReferenceNote and TaskNote. They both inherited from BaseNote.

When I create a new note I have type in the request and depending on that type I create the corresponding model.

But how can I get the corresponding model when I need to get the note by `id`?

My current solution:

```
$base_note = BaseNote::find($id);

$note = $note_factory->getNote($base_note);
```

In Factory:

```
function getNote(BaseNote $base_note) {
    if ($base_note->type === self::REFERENCE_NOTE_TYPE) {
        $note = new ReferenceNote($base_note->getAttributes());
        //logic of adding additional attributes for reference note
    } else {
        $note = new TaskNote($base_note->getAttributes());
        //logic of adding additional attributes for task note
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you really need the concrete type? Wouldn't be the superclass sufficient?

Comment: Each class has its own properties which superclass doesn't.